# Using batch file I need to know the latest folder name in the particular location

Tags: batch-file

I have a network location from where I need to know the name of latest folder created.
This I want to do using batch file.
Any help will be great

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last created directory batch command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519389/get-last-created-directory-batch-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by the following way:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir "<directory name>" /AD /O-D /B') do (set recent=%%A& goto exit)

:exit
echo %recent%
```

Any better solution can be good.

Comment: There's a space between `recent=%%A` and `&`. Keep in mind that it will be appended to `%%A`.