# Get last created directory batch command

Tags: batch-file

How can i get newest subfolder in directory ? 
I need it in `MKLINK /D` command.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237324/how-to-find-the-last-directory-created-in-batch/20149008#20149008

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET a=%%i
echo Most recent subfolder: %a%
```

*(`%i` for windows 10)*

- `/b` is for bare format
- `/ad-h` only directories, but not the hidden ones
- `t:c` means to use the creation date for sorting (use `t:w` for last write date)
- `/od` sort oldest first
- The `for /F` executes the command and sets a to the directory name, the last one is the newest one.

If you execute this directly on the command line (not in a batch file), use `%` instead of `%%`.

This works with the *current directory* - as @iesou pointed out you'll need to add the directory path after `dir` if you need to use any other directory path.

Example with specified directory path:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "c:\Program Files" /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET a=%%i
```

---

To prevent going through all subfolders, you may change the sort order to have the most recent first (`/o-d`) and exit the for loop after the first call:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (
    SET a=%%i
    GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof
:found
echo Most recent subfolder: %a%
```

Comment: +1 To clarify after the `dir` and before the `/b` you need to enter the root directory. Also you don't need the echo if it is part of a batch. You can simply use the `%a%` variable because the last value it was set to is the newest directory.

Comment: @iesou That's correct - if you don't specify the directory, the current directory is used. Added it to the answer, and provided a slightly modified version.

Comment: @marapet I have used the above script however if the folder has a space in it, it does not work, have I missed something?

Comment: @Arthor You are correct, the for command uses default options. You may change `FOR /F %%i` into `FOR /F "delims=" %%i` to prevent splitting up the directory name.

Answer (score 6):

Some improvement for dir names with spaces

```
FOR /F " tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /od') DO (SET a=%%i)
```

now you get a=Application Data instead of a=Application
Note: Pay attention to the space in front of "tokens"

Comment: Another improvement to ignore some matches: DO if not "%%i"==".." if not "%%i"=="." SET