# Batch Script for Finding Success or Failed from Log File

Tags: batch-file

I have a log file in windows server, in that daily log will be created, so I have to take success and failure count in that file.

I need a batch script to take a count from recent updated file.

**findstr /i "success: failed:" "C:\test*.log" > C:\test\result.txt**

This is the code I used but I need a command to take count in latest created file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details about operating system and batch script language (Perl script, windows batch file, ...), explain what you have tried so far, and include your code as it is now. Starting from that, people may be able (and willing) to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for just printing:

```
findstr /i "success failed" logfile.txt
```

to put it into a variable and print:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i "success failed" logfile.txt') do (
  set line=%%i
  echo !line!
)
```

**EDIT**

`for /?` gives some useful options, like searching for complete words (e.g. find "**end**", but not "M**end**oza", "b**end**" or "**end**ing"):

```
 findstr /i "\<success\> \<failed\>" logfile.txt
```

`\<` means "start of word", `\>` means "end of word"

If you know the capitalization of your searchwords, you can also omit `/i`

Comment: hi stephan, thanks it was working but, one more doubt, i want only success and failed count in log, file. i used your command. it was printing all the words have success like. It printing successfully word also.. please help me to find exact success and failed alone.not to print prefix word.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan, you are great.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan, you are great. last one ... this is working fine. there have one path, in that path daily files are getting updated, I have to go into recent updated file and then have to find this failed and success count. Now I am able to take the failed and success count because of your help. Now I need a command to go in to recent updated file and then have to take this success and failure count.

Comment: `FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /t:c /od') DO SET last=%%i`(slightly adapted for files from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10519606/2152082))